# Extends in Android using listview and navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, extends, navigation-drawer

I've got an activity with a listview so my `extends` in my MainActivity is a `ListActivity` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{
```

I want implement the new Navigation Drawer but i saw that the extends is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

How can i solve? Can i use the navigation drawer with a listview activity?

Comment: yes you can what is your min sdk in manifest

Comment: use MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity and inflate list just as usual view

Comment: the min sdk is 9 actually but i have to change it i think..

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov what do you mean with `inflate list just as usual view`?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                />

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@drawable/menu_list_divider"
            android:background="@color/very_dark_gray"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

        private ListView list;
        private ArrayAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.your_view);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter...
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }    

    }
```

Comment: it is better to have a framelayout and you can replace the fragments later

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to implement lists without extending `ListActivity`. Have a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample) article. It shows an example of lists without the `ListActivity`.

Comment: It's section `1.5. ListView example`, I linked to it, but you need to scroll up a little. This shows how to use a `ListView` without extending the specific activity. As @Georgy Gobozov mentions, you can then extends `ActionBarActivity`. I recommend to get the list to work first, and then to add the action bar.

Comment: yes! I mean, i have an activity (MainActivity) that is a listview.. And if possible, i want implement a navigation drawer... Although i need to create a sliding menu but i prefere the drawer..

Comment: @David_D you can have a lsitview not a problem but you need to extend ActionBarActivity

Comment: before i need know an important thing, is possible with nav drawer open activities instead fragments?

Comment: No, all options in the navigation drawer have to be fragments.

Comment: If you want to implement all this, I'd advice to first add the ActionBar following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html), and then to add the navigation drawer, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: have a fragment with a lsitview your framelayout is the container for fragment